# jQuery function on Autofill form data?

Tags: jquery

Need to call a function calculate, wrote:

```
$(".crednumber,.chequeamount").live('keyup  blur',function(){
    calculatePaidAmount();
});
```

but when data is filled through autofill the function is called only in blur.
Need to call the function in change of the value by autofill.

Comment: adding an event handler for the `onchange` event as well should handle that

Answer (score 0):

If the form was filled using auto-fill, the `onchange` event will still fire, so you need to handle that event as well:

```
$(".crednumber,.chequeamount").live('keyup  blur change',function(){
    calculatePaidAmount();
});
```

Comment: For jQuery should be just `change`.

Comment: but blur will call the function only when the its clicked out na , want to call the function when value is changed

Comment: @user1256784: Which is why I added the change event to the handler as well. If a user manually enters the value and leaves the box, the blur event will fire. If autofill fills out the box, the change event will fire.